# Adding a className on scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add a `className` when the page scrolls? I have ready many other articles and answers to this (may be a duplicate) but none have helped me understand what is wrong with my code below.

If the code is not the issue I believe that it stems from a `perspective` wrapper around the app that may disallow the registration of scroll. How can I add the event listener to register scroll on `id=container`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      isStuck: true,
  }
this.handleHeaderStuck = this.handleHeaderStuck.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}

handleHeaderStuck() {
  if (window.scrollY === 0 && this.state.isStuck === true) {
      this.setState({isStuck: false});
  }
  else if (window.scrollY !== 0 && this.state.isStuck !== true) {
      this.setState({isStuck: true});
  }
}

render() {

  return (
    <main className={this.state.isStuck ? 'header-stuck' : ''}>
       ...
    </main>
```

[image]

This screenshot reassures me that the issue is with the registering of onScroll listener

Comment: In the constructor, initialize `isStuck: false`. When it is set to `true` the first time you start scrolling, none of the conditions will be `true` and so the state never updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your component have enough height for scroll. Your code works.
Add some height to main and check it.

```
main {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/156204/

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I thought and figured as much - unfortunately setting the height is a no-go too. I think it is due to several factors relating to being within a container of an offscreen menu. I am trying to find a way to set the scrollY to a certain `div id="container"`, do you know any?

Comment: Yes, just by simply logging the scrollY position `const scrollpos = window.scrollY` `console.log(scrollpos);` in my app I get `0` always. In your jsFiddle you get the position always registering. I think I need to open another question relating more to scrollY. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just incase you were interested - my issue as just uncovered was due to `overflow: hidden;` being applied to the `body`. It was meant to only be applied during modals but I messed that up. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, it happens) I am glad to help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You code has an issue, `onScroll` is attached a listener function `handleScroll` whereas the function is `handleHeaderStuck` in your case. Change the listener to execute the correct function.

```
componentDidMount () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleHeaderStuck);
}
```

Comment: Whoops - thanks. This was more of a copy paste issue when adding to the question. My app is running with your suggestion and not the issue. I will change my question. Cheers.

Comment: @Darren, do you mean that the problem is still there or is it solved

Comment: Problem is still there. When adding the code to my question I copied and pasted from an old file. The app does not work with the suggestion.